# StringLengthAttribute MVC Blank Space at end

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

Okay so I have an attribute set like below. if someone types in a name even one character over the 15 characters they get an error message. This is the expected way it should work except I found one issue. If there are 15 characters plus a blank space at the end of those 15 characters the error is not caught. Why is that and how do I prevent it.

Examples. "Santa Fe MAMMAL " <-- Validation does not catch this.
          "Santa Fe MAMMALS" <-- Validation does catch this.

```
[StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "CallerID can be no more than 15 Characters in length including spaces")]
    public string CompanyNameCallerID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Because blank space is a character?

Comment: Yes the Blank space is a character so the validation should catch it as being over the 15 character limit. Unfortunately the validation does not catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is strange behavior, but what we can do :(

I think you can't handle it by StringLengthAttribute  (or I don't know how) but you can do these things:

- Regular expression

`[RegularExpression(@"^(.*\S)?$"), ErrorMessage = "Some error message")]`

However what I see for problem here is that it will not match any string with space in the end  (any count of characters)

- Trim on property - something like

  `private string m_CompanyNameCallerID = string.Empty;
   get { return this.m_CompanyNameCallerID; }
   set { this.m_CompanyNameCallerID = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) ? value : value.Trim(); }`

Comment: Although this is not the ultimate solution it does work and works just fine for the solution I need it for. I do wish I knew why it failed the other way though. I think I am going to post this in the MSDN Forum and see if I get any bites on the issue.

Comment: Now I am thinking that better can be remove StringLength attribute and use this Regex: `[RegularExpression(@"^(.{0,14}\S)?$", ErrorMessage = "Error")] `. It will allow 0-15 long text which is not ending with space.